# SlidingDrawer for Winrt?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

In Android, there is a widget call `SlidingDrawer` , I was wondering if C#/XAML have something similar where I can hide my content and drag out my content when needed. [image]

Like this except , **from top to bottom**. I have already looked at `AppsBar` which isn't enough of what I need. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why is the AppBar not sufficient?

Comment: I need to add a scrollable list to it. Im not sure but I don't think AppBar is able to add a scrollable list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is there, though it could be fairly easy to implement. A different problem is that the AppBar should be sufficient and better in most scenarios since it does not require anything to pull it out.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 design guidelines suggest that you should use App Bars for the kind of control you're looking to integrate, you can find more information and details on how to do the implementation here:

[Quickstart: adding app bars (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781232.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's a `DrawerLayout` project on GitHub:

https://github.com/amarmesic/windows-phone-navigation-drawer

It's available via NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DrawerLayout/